# Android Volley: select data from MySQL database by id specified by user

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-volley

I'm writing a simple Android application using **Volley**. I'd like to know how to select a first name and a last name from MySQL database by ID, **which user enter into editText in application**. This is my PHP script:

```
 <?php
    include 'connection.php';

    global $connect;
    $id = $_POST["id"];

    $query = "SELECT firstName, lastName FROM users WHERE id = '$id'";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $response = array();

    if($number_of_rows > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $response[] = $row;
        }
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array("users"=>$response));
    mysqli_close($connect);

?>
```

If I specified the ID in the code, it returns a data in JSON, which I demand, so the script and the database are ok. The response which I get for $id=1 is:

```
{"users":[{"firstName":"Jonash","lastName":"Corvin"}]}
```

And this is my code of StringRequest:

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

            String firstName = jsonObject.getString("firstName");
            String lastName = jsonObject.getString("lastName");

            firstNameTV.setText(firstName);
            lastNameTV.setText(lastName);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
}) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        parameters.put("id", idEditText.getText().toString());
        return parameters;
    }
    };
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't do anything... It even doesn't show any error or toast message. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Please share your JSON response you are getting.

Comment: I added. There was a little mistake in variable name (I've changed the names in a hurry for more clarity), but it's not a reason.

Comment: Your JSON Parsing is wrong. @Corgan

Comment: Hmm, could you tell me what exactly is wrong? I did it in the same way which I saw on one of the YT tutorial and there it was working correctly.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> {"users":[{"firstName":"Jonash","lastName":"Corvin"}]}

According to the given JSON you need to parse the JSON like this:

```
JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("users");
JSONObject data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

String firstName = data.getString("firstName");
String lastName = data.getString("lastName");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_TRANSACTION_DETAILS,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Log.i(TAG,response.toString());
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("read");

                                if (success.equals("1")) {
                                    Toast.makeText(Activity.this,"Data Fetched!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String firstName= object.getString("firstName").trim();
                                    String lastName= object.getString("lastName").trim();
                                    }
}
catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(Activity.this,"Json Login Error " +e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }}},
new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(Activity.this,"Volley Login Error " +error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                })

        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("id", id);
                return params;
            }
        };
```

Comment: Usually is a very good practice to explain your code, and not only pasting code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

On your PHP code change $connect to $conn, this will solve your concern

```
<?php
    include 'connection.php';

    global $connect;
    $id = $_POST["id"];

    $query = "SELECT firstName, lastName FROM users WHERE id = '$id'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);  //<--------change
    $number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $response = array();

    if($number_of_rows > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $response[] = $row;
        }
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array("users"=>$response));
    mysqli_close($conn);  //<--------change

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  <?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        require_once 'connection.php'
        $sql = "SELECT firstName, lastName FROM users WHERE id='$id' ";
        $response = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $result = array();
        $result['read'] = array();
        if( mysqli_num_rows($response) === 1 ) {      
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response)) {
                 $h['firstName']        = $row['firstName'] ;
                 $h['lastName']       = $row['lastName'] ;
                 array_push($result["read"], $h);
                 $result["success"] = "1";
                 echo json_encode($result);
            }
       }
     }else {
         $result["success"] = "0";
         $result["message"] = "Error!";
         echo json_encode($result);
         mysqli_close($conn);
     }
     ?>
```